# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, But the file is there

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

Error Message says from the taskhandler.py : 
`with open('./tasks.csv','r') as task_data:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './tasks.csv'`

But it is actually there :

```html
.
├── feature
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── styles
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── termcolor.pyc
│   │   ├── text_style.py
│   ├── taskhandler.py
│   └── tasks.csv
├── __init__.py
├── start.py

1 directories, 8 files
```

Here is the code for the `taskhandler.py`

```py
...

def update_program(taskobj):
     with open('./tasks.csv','r') as task_data:
         csv_reader = csv.reader(task_data)

         next(csv_reader)

         for line in csv_reader:

             if line in taskobj:
                 pass
             else:
                 taskobj.append(line)

     task_data.close()

...
```

So how to get around this problem? Is there a mistake with the way i am openning the file? I tried it on my other computer and it works normally.

**UPDATE**

**Note :**
If you want to see the whole source code, go ahead to my [github account](https://github.com/abhishtagatya/PyDo-List) or if you wanted to try the program and see the actual error, `pip3 install pydotask` and type in your terminal `pydo`. Some of the code and directory above are slightly edited and reconfigured in github and pip installation. But the problem remains the same.

This is a CLI Program, so i suggest trying it with Linux.

Comment: There may be a file named "tasks.csv", but the program is likely looking in a different place. "./" doesn't refer to where the script is located, it refers to the current working directory. Those can be two entirely different locations. It's safe to assume that if python is saying "file not found", it's not there.

Comment: have you tried `open("tasks.csv")` already (ommiting the "./")?

Comment: Before your with-statement do `import os; print(os.getcwd())`.  You will see that the current directory is not the directory that contains `tasks.csv`. You will need to provide the correct absolute or relative path (`os.path.join(parent_path, 'tasks.csv')`).  (You could instead change the working directory with `os.chdir()`, but don't do that.)

Comment: yes rafael, i have tried it but it just gave the same results

Comment: I think youre on to something steven, thanks for the suggestion! i will try it :)

Answer (score -2):

The csv file is in the same folder so you could try `with open('tasks.csv','r') as task_data` directly. 
I hope this help you.

Comment: No.  If `with open('tasks.csv','r') as task_data` works then `with open('./tasks.csv','r') as task_data` also works.  Just because `taskhandler.py` is in the same directory as `tasks.csv` doesn't mean that the script was launched from the same directory or that the working directory wasn't changed.  For all we know `taskhandler.py` is imported by `start.py`.